# Add to cart validation

Tags: php, ajax, woocommerce

I need to check a product before adding it to cart.
I used this function:

```
function so_validate_add_cart_item( $passed, $product_id, $quantity,$variation_id = '', $variations= '' ) {
// do your validation, if not met switch $passed to false
if ( 1 != 2 ){
    $passed = false;
    wc_add_notice( __( 'You can not do that', 'textdomain' ), 'error' );
}
return $passed;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'so_validate_add_cart_item', 10, 5 );
```

This works fine because I see the error message, but the product is added to the cart. Instead I need that it doesn't add the product and it will show the error message. I think is a problem with ajax maybe?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe something else is switching `$passed` back to `true`. Try a later priority (ie: switch `10` to `20`)

Comment: I tried your code, there is nothing wrong... it works as expected... it did not add the item to the cart...

Comment: it's works for the first time, i've implemented a code and somethimes doesn't work.